# Request.Params understands [+] for a space

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm doing a request...something like this:

```
@Request.Params["id"].ToString()
```

the value of id is encripted and returns something like
`ZK10ez/BJARTw GVLbIeUOp`

instead of

`ZK10ez/BJARTw+GVLbIeUOp` <- this is what is passed in the URL

In other words, it's replacing my plus sign [+] with spaces [ ].
I could just do a replace, but I don't know if this will happen in the future with other letters.

Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A + character in a URL represents a space character.  This is an aspect of [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding).

Make sure that you properly URL encode any data before using it in a URL.  You should not try and replicate URL encoding / decoding by doing your own string replacements.

You can use [Url.Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode.aspx) to encode your data prior to using it in a query string.